# Switch Case in Freemarker : TemplateException

Tags: templates, exception, freemarker

Here's my `testMacro.txt`

```
<#macro myMacro value1 value2>
<#list 1..value1 as x>
 <#if x=value1>
      <#switch value2>
           <#case value2 = 1>
                CASE1    
           <#break>
           <#case value2 =2 >
                CASE2   
           <#break>
           <#case value2 = 3>
                CASE3    
           <#break>
      </#switch>
 <#else>
             ELSE
 </#if>
</#list>
```

```
<@myMacro value1=3 value2=1 />
```

Here is the Exception that I am getting.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: freemarker.template.TemplateException: The only legal comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, or two dates.
Left  hand operand is a freemarker.template.SimpleNumber
Right hand operand is a freemarker.template.TemplateBooleanModel$2`

Now this is in the switch case statement, though line number is not given in the exception, but I commented the switch statement and there was no exception, hence I am concluding that its some problem with the case statement.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons `=` is an alias of `==`, except on places where an assignment is expected.  So `'<#case value2 = 1>'` is `'<#case value2 == 1>'`, and thus it ends up being `'<#case true>'` or `'<#case false>'`, hence the error message. So as you have figured, it should be `'<#case 1>'` and such, just like in C-ish languages. As of the last example in the Manual, that example is wrong...

Comment: took me an entire day, I think I was just lucky. :)
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out if I do the following

```
       <#case 1>
            CASE1    
       <#break>
       <#case 2 >
            CASE2   
       <#break>
       <#case 3>
            CASE3    
       <#break>
```

then it does seem to be working. Though I dont get why would it not work with the expression, since I saw that from the [Freemarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_switch.html)

Comment: value, refValue1, etc.: Expressions evaluates to scalars of the same type.

From the manual.